# BLE (blue tooth low energy) : what is the difference between encryption and whitening regarding to packets?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

In BLE, what is the difference between encrypted packets and whitened packets?
Is the whole packet encrypt/whitened or just the payload?

- I know that whitening is used to "whiten" the signal so there is less 0000000.... and 1111....
- I know that encryption is used to "encrypt" the signal with a key (sym or asym), so the packet (or just payload?) is not readable for non key-holders.

I'm testing a low lever driver for BLE stack, and I want to know what to expect while testing encryption and whitening.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the exact question is? You've kind of described whitening and encryption.

Comment: "Is the whole packet encrypt/whitened or just the payload?"

Answer (score 1):

Whitening 'whitens' the **whole** packet.

- Whitening happens after CRC generation in a tx packet.
- Unwhitening happens before CRC checking in a rx packet.

Encryption 'encrypts' only the payload of the packet (not the header, nor the length).

- Encryption happens before CRC generation in a tx packet.
- Decryption happens after CRC checking in a rx packet.